# Connection to remote server hangs indefinitely

Tags: networking, firewall, port

I have a server running Fedora 23. When I run a simple server application on it (the example given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/), only with the port and IP address changed) it opens port 3490 and listens for the client to connect. Once the client connects it is supposed to responds, and end. However the client program when run on a remote machine just hangs indefinitely and never connects.
Here is the output of `netstat -tuplen` on the server while the server side program is running. Program is "./server" here.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          581266095  139/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          581266893  178/sendmail: accep 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3490            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          1781896327 23696/./server      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          581266097  139/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      27         1762178376 18622/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          581266785  149/httpd
```

When I try to telnet in to the port while the software is running I get `Trying [server IP]...` until it times out. When I run the server and client software on the same machine, and just connect locally over 127.0.0.1, they work perfectly.

While the server software is running I preformed a scan with nmap on my remote machine, specifically `nmap -T4 -A -v [server IP]/3490`. It picks up the ssh port "22" I was connected to at the time from a third machine, but not the 3490 port, or any other port for that matter. The traceroute is 12 hops long from my local machine to the server, if that influences anything.

Before running the server application I ran

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3490 -j ACCEPT
```

and then

```
service iptables save
```

to allow connections to the port through the firewall.
However while this may have opened up the port on the firewall, it didn't let the client and server programs connect. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change? Where should I check to learn more about the problem and get closer to fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't *actually* allowed the connections through the firewall.

*Iptables* rules are read **top-to-bottom**, "first match wins", so if your INPUT chain had a global 'block all' rule at the end, anything added below that rule is simply never checked. Run `iptables-save` or `iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers` and just read your INPUT rules from top to bottom to see what checks are made to the packet.

The `-A` in the command means "append" and adds the new rule at the end. The opposite is `-I`, "insert", which places it at the top; both also take a specific position number to place the rule before/after. For example, if you want to add the new rule at position 4:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp ... -j ...
```

You can also do this:

```
iptables-save > rules.txt
nano rules.txt
iptables-restore < rules.txt
```

---

Note that a firewall may exist elsewhere, e.g. packets may be filtered by the server's network. Use `tcpdump` to determine whether the packets at least *reach* the server:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 "port 3490"
```

Comment: I have `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` after the input for port 22 but before my addition to port 3490 and `-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` at the very end right before `COMMIT`. I'm guessing this is the "block all" you mentioned, though I'm not sure how to deal with it.

I tried the tcp dump command you provided. Telneting in from my machine I could watch my packets knock on the firewall, which is comforting.

Comment: You deal with it by inserting your port 3490 rule at the correct position (say, at the very beginning or somewhere in the middle), instead of at the end of INPUT. (Don't pay any attention to the FORWARD chain; it does not apply to your packet.)